# Get-Cluster cmdlet fails when using -Name param

Tags: powershell, cluster, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

**Summary**

When I call `Get-Cluster` powershell returns the name of my cluster.  For simplicity sake, lets call it `Cluster1`.  If I call `Get-Cluster -Name Cluster1` it fails with an error.

**Error:**

```
Get-Cluster : Check the spelling of the cluster name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. Make sure
the cluster nodes are turned on and connected to the network or contact your network administrator.
    The RPC server is unavailable
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Cluster -Name Cluster1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (:) [Get-Cluster], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterRpcConnection,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.GetClusterCommand
```

**Detail**

My first thought is that I'm using the cmdlet wrong or winrm isn't working (it is).  I also thought that maybe there's a difference in the way it's called that's causing the failure.  Following that logic I reviewed the following technet page on the cmdlet:

*Research*: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh847254(v=wps.630).aspx

Based on the writing there, I couldn't discern an obvious user error.  So I've tried a few things to figure it out.  First I thought maybe I'm just constantly screwing up the typing so I did this:

```
$Cluster = Get-Cluster
($cluster.Name -like "Cluster1")
```

The conditional returns `True` so I'm not a cluster f at typing.  Next I tried the following:

```
Get-Cluster | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "Cluster1"}
```

Which of course returns the cluster object.  So, what's going on here?  What's different with `Get-Cluster -Name "Cluster1"`?

**Edit**

Version info from Powershell:

```
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17090
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: There aren't any special characters in the name of the actual cluster, are there?

Comment: Great question!  No there aren't.  It's all alphanumeric (EN-US).  That'd be too easy :)

Comment: Are you running this on a member of the cluster or from a machine that is not a member via remoting? I ran it on my test cluster on a machine that is a member of the cluster without the quotes (It's running 2012, not 2012R2), and had no problem.

Comment: I'm running it from an elevated powershell prompt on one of the cluster nodes.  Also, quotes or no, it still fails if I use the name param :(

Comment: What's the Powershell version? ($psversiontable)

Comment: see updated question

Comment: Crazy question for you: if you run `nslookup Cluster1` or `ping Cluster1` from the same machine, does it work correctly? Question 2: is your firewall enabled?

Comment: Still not seeing the same behavior, even with upgrading to 4.0.

Comment: Works as expected here. A better test would probably be to use -eq instead of -like in your tests. Do these work as well? Remember that the Name parameter for the Get-Cluster command expects the cluster name, and not a node name.

Comment: In my experience, the `-Name` parameter will work with any name that resolves to the cluster or any  of its nodes. This is why I was asking about DNS and firewall. When you run the command without `-Name` it checks the local cluster service, but when you use `-Name` it actually makes a remote connection to whatever is behind that name. I suspect it does this whether that name is the local machine or not.

Comment: @briantist if you can cite sources, write that up as the answer and I'll accept it.  Remember, my question is what's different when you use the -name switch.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my observation of running `Get-Cluster` against a few of the clusters I have at work, it seemed to me that `-Name` uses name resolution, so if there's anything that causes a problem resolving names, it will fail even if the name you give it is the local machine.

I tried it with cluster names and cluster service names as well as names of the individual nodes in the cluster.

I also added an entry in my HOSTS file pointing a fake name to one of the clusters, and was able to successfully use that name with `Get-Cluster`.

To me this strongly suggests that the use of `-Name` relies entirely on standard name resolution in the OS.

The case where `Get-Cluster` without name would work whereas `Get-Cluster -Name localhost` (or the actual hostname of the current machine) would not work, suggests to me that without a name parameter, `Get-Cluster` attempts to communicate with the cluster service directly on the current machine, which would not require any name resolution.

In addition to name resolution, I believe that an RPC connection is made to the destination server when using `-Name` (even if it's the local machine), so even if name resolution works, the RPC service actually being unavailable, or a firewall being on could actually block that connection and cause the error you saw.

I was not able to test this, as I don't currently have a cluster in our test environment and I can't intentionally break name resolution or RPC on a production cluster!

Unfortunately, I could not back up this hypothesis with any kind of authoritative source (I couldn't find a definitive description of this behavior).